# Erro : "No Persistence provider for EntityManager"

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

Tenho um projeto no Eclipse com uma aplicação que persiste no banco de dados Postgresql 9.6 através do Hibernate, mas o Java não está reconhecendo a **"persistence-unit name"** que está setada no **persistence.xml**, mesmo este nome conferindo com o nome passado para o objeto "EntityManagerFactory".

Segue abaixo o log da exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named bd2_persistence_unit
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at br.com.bd2.teste.TesteDatabase.main(TesteDatabase.java:15)
```

Este é o código da minha main:

```
package br.com.bd2.teste;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import br.com.bd2.exemplo.model.Fruteira;

public class TesteDatabase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Inicializacao da fabrica de objetos
        // persistenceUnitName = "bd2", ou seja, relaciona com a conexao na
        // persistence.xml (podera ter "n" unidades de persistencia)
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("bd2_persistence_unit");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        // Os comandos a seguir devem ser executados "um por vez"
        // Inserindo...
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(new Fruteira("Fruteira"));
        em.persist(new Fruteira("Fruteira 3"));
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        // Atualizando...
        // Buscara a fruteira com id = 1. Observe o numero do id pelo pgAdmin3!
        Fruteira fruteira = em.find(Fruteira.class, 1L); 
        if (fruteira != null) {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            fruteira.setNome("Fruteira Legal");
            em.merge(fruteira);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        // Recuperando "n" objetos...
        TypedQuery<Fruteira> q = em.createQuery("SELECT f " +
                                                "FROM Fruteira f", Fruteira.class);
        for (Fruteira each : q.getResultList()) {
            System.out.println(each.toString());
        }       

        // Excluindo...
        // Buscara a fruteira com id = 1. Observe o numero do id pelo pgAdmin3!
        fruteira = em.find(Fruteira.class, 1L); 
        if (fruteira != null) {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.remove(fruteira);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }

        // Recuperando "n" objetos...
        q = em.createQuery("FROM Fruteira f", Fruteira.class);
        for (Fruteira each : q.getResultList()) {
            System.out.println(each.toString());
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Esta é a organização do meu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o meu xml de configuração do Hibernate:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
        version="2.1">


        <persistence-unit name="bd2_persistence_unit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider> 


            <class>br.com.bd2.exemplo.model.Fruteira</class>
            <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

            <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />

                <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/bd2" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="postgres" />
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />          

                <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="true" />
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>

    </persistence>
```

Comment: Talvez a tag `provider` no persistence.xml?

  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

Comment: @IsraelMerljak Fiz isso e o problema persiste. :(

Comment: Amigo.. a tag provider é dentro do persistence-unit. Dependendo da versão do hibernate tbm pode `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider`.

Comment: @IsraelMerljak Corrigido, não adiantou. O nome da unidade de persistência pode ser qualquer um né,? Não precisa ter a ver com o nome do meu banco que está rodando no Postgree não é?

Comment: Sim.. o nome da PU pode ser o que você quiser. desde que a url esteja apontando pra base correta.. cara.. da uma olhada nessa [pergunta](https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named-22769) no forum da Alura. É um problema bastante parecido com o seu. Foi sugerido verificar as bibliotecas no projeto. Segundo a resposta lá, me parece que ta faltando o hibernate-entitymanager no seu classpath.

Comment: Ok, vou verificar.

Comment: Coloquei na classpath o Entity Manager e continua o erro...

Answer (score -1):

No seu persistence.xml, ou arquivo que você configura a persistência do hibernate tem uma tag  ali tem um atributo name.

Esses names devem ser o mesmo.